# Null Pointer Exception that shouldnt happen

Tags: java, arraylist

So i have some code that i am using to create up to four objects of the class `player`. This object only needs one string passed to the constructor.

```
int players = view.newGameBox();
for (int i = 1; i <= players; i++) {
    model.add(new player(view.playerName(i)));
}

ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
for (player pname : model) {
    names.add(pname.Name());
}
view.setNames(names);
```

`view.newGameBox()` returns an int that indicates the number of players to be created.

`model` is an arraylist of type `player`

`view.newPlayerName` is used to get user input for the name for each player.

Each time i run the code, no matter how it is structured, a `NullPointerException`always fires on the `model.add(new player(view.playerName(i)));` line. Is there something about arraylists that i am missing?

Comment: What do you instantiate your model to? You should have model = new XXXXXList(); somewhere or model is null :)

Comment: your problem looks in view.playerName(i) check what is happening in this, can you share code inside playerName(int) method

Comment: where do you declare the model list?

Comment: Did you verify that `model` and `view` are not null?

Comment: Try splitting this line `model.add(new player(view.playerName(i)));` in two lines and then you will see where is the null pointer exactly.

Comment: You get the exception because (duh!!) you have a null pointer.  Show some initiative, do some debugging, and figure out which pointer is null.  Then figure out why.

Comment: @Pphoenix god i'm a fool! still getting used to java!

Comment: You need to post a stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either your `model` is `null`, or something inside `view.playerName(i)` throws this exception. On this line

```
model.add(new player(view.playerName(i)));
```

two expressions can cause a `NullPointerException` - `model.add()` and `view.playerName()`. Since `view` is not `null` (otherwise, `view.newGameBox()` would crash) it is either `model`, or it's some other line inside `view.playerName(i)`.

Comment: Yeah, i just checked it and i was missing the initialization of the list.. i declared it but forgot to initialize! Still getting used to java...